# How do I force the mouse cursor to change without a mouse movement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In my webpage, testing on Chrome, I have a button div. The button is styled so that it has a hover state in a different colour, and a hand-shaped mouse pointer. All this is fine.

When the button is pressed, it triggers an animation, and I don't want to let the user press the button again until it's done, so I put a semi-opaque div over the top to block the button.

The problem comes when the animation completes and the div is removed. The mouse pointer is over the button but the hover state isn't active until the user actually moves the mouse, then the mouse pointer changes and all is well.

Note that the click still works - this is a purely cosmetic (but annoying) aberration.

Can I force the browser to re-evaluate the point under the cursor?

Comment: Good question. Just out of curiousity, does the div covering the button stop keyboard access to it?

Comment: pseudocode- button onclick = ((){ button.disabled = "disabled"; startAnimation(); button.removeAttribute(disabled); })() - Where button is an html elemenet from getElementById or getElementsByTagName().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to prevent input to a button is to disable it. You can toggle the cursor style with the CSS cursor property.

**Javascript:**

```
var theButton = document.getElementById('theButton');
    theButton.disabled = true;
    theButton.setAttribute('style','cursor:default;');

// animation is complete

theButton.disabled = false;
theButton.removeAttribute('style');
```

**jQuery:**

```
var $theButton = $('#theButton').prop('disabled',true).css('cursor','default');

// animation is complete

$theButton.prop('disabled',false).css('cursor','pointer');
```

Comment: Ah.. perhaps the problem is that I'm not using a button, I'm using a div with a hover state. I should probably look into using a button...

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I misread that part of your question. Yes I would recommend using a button. `<input type="button"' can be styled just as flexibly as a `<div>`, it's more semantically correct, gracefully degrades, and is better for accessibility (screen-readers, mobile devices, etc)

Comment: I'm running into this issue and this did not fix it in Chrome :\

Answer (score 1):

Check the position of the mouse when the animation ends and you remove the div, or just always store them and check that value when it ends to see if the cursor is still over your button. You could do this with `event.clientX, event.clientY or event.pageX, event.pageY` something similar to those(not completely sure just did some quick research but those seemed to work in chrome,IE, and firefox). Then if the mouse is still over the button, trigger the on.hover for the button element again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the root of your question was to how to prevent double animating. Instead of placing a `<div>` over it, you can just do it with JavaScript.

Set a global variable called `isAnimating` to true when you start your animation. At the top of your click handler add this line `if (isAnimating) return false;` Obviously, you need to set `isAnimating` to `false` as soon as the animation is completed, either through a timer or in some kind of callback function.

This will prevent double animating, without doing anything silly with the DOM that would affect the hover states, or so I'd hope!

Let me know if that's not what you meant and I'll take another look at it!

Comment: he doesn't just want to know when the button is not animated but also if the cursor stayed on the button. If it moved then he has no issue. He only has a problem when the mouse has not moved so nothing has activated the hover. So your answer would make the hover activate even if the mouse was no longer on the button which would of course be bad.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the curser of all elements using the * wildcard in jquery. See if this will update the cursor.